# How to get list items same values in each two list items to display in 3rd list using with caml query

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, sharepoint-addin, caml, linq

[image]

How can I write one caml query to get items from two lists joined on empid? 
will you please anybody give me help with suitable caml query or even otherwise possible code.

***Note:*** There is no lookup coumns in this two lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in three steps:

1 Grab all the items of the two lists

2 Check the items that are equal. Save the Id of the items that have the same value

3 Register the items of you got id  in the list 3

You can improve this logic, but basically this is what you should do

You should write the query according to your need